# PyGame won't render _ text smbol

Tags: python, pygame, text-rendering

So I'm trying to make a menu screen for a game I'm making with python in PyGame and everything works fine except for the actual image of the screen itself. The game I'm making is text-based and when I blit a line of text on screen with the _ character it gets replaced with a space. This doesn't happen if it's not over a space or another _. I made sure that my string was working correctly and it seems solely to do with either the font.render() command of the screen.blit() command. I would like to know if there is some weird feature that keeps certain symbols from being rendered or blitted normally. Thanks for any help you can give me.
*Note: This is strictly for multi-line string rendering, please see code for how I do this. I render each line separately and then update the screen once they are all rendered.

```
    lines = multi_line_text.split("\n")
    tempplace = 0
    place = 5#starting pixel positioning
    while tempplace != len(lines):
        text = font.render(lines[tempplace], False, white, black)
        game_window.blit(text, (5, place))
        place = place + 15#Pixel positioning increment
        tempplace = tempplace + 1
```

Comment: can you show what you get when you run `print(multi_line_text)`

Comment: I meant any multi-line string you wanted to add, I was trying to keep the question general.

Comment: You are drawing lines by blitting entire rectangles top to bottom. I bet you are *overwriting* the underscores with the next rectangle. To fix, increase the vertical distance between the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question. I realized my mistake was in the fact I didn't give my text enough room between lines, thereby cutting-off the symbol with the next line. Sorry for not realizing it sooner!I'll accept this as the answer and close the question as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

can you share your code, I'm rendering "hello_world" fine with pygame with this code

```
def draw_text(text, size=20, color=white, x=0, y=0):

    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", size)
    label = myfont.render(text, 1, color)
    screen.blit(label, (x,y))
```

then somewhere in your while loop call `draw_text("hello_world")`

[image]

Comment: Not quite like that. I'll alter my original question to make it more clear.